# How to do conditional browser interactions with intern

Tags: intern

With the promised web driver I would like to check if an element exists on the page, then login if it does, otherwise continue with the promise chain.

Is this not possible at the moment due to https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/14?

Comment: This issue is also related: https://github.com/theintern/intern/issues/53

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Intern 2, simply use the normal `find` command:

```js
var remote = this.remote;
remote.get(url)
    .findById('foo')
    .then(function (element) {
        // exists
    }, function () {
        // does not exist
    });
```

In Intern 1, if you need to conditionally branch, you’ll need to stop and add new instructions based on the result of your check.

```js
var remote = this.remote;
remote.get(url)
    .elementByIdIfExists('foo')
    .then(function (element) {
        if (element) {
            remote.clickElement()
                .type('foo');
                // ...etc.
        }
    });
```

This should work in Intern 1.1 **only** if you are adding new commands to the remote promise chain when there are **no other already-existing commands pending**. Intern 1.2 will contain improvements that eliminate this restriction. This is issue #14.

Comment: How is this now done with intern 2? I see no trace of 'find if exists' type commands in leadfoot.

Comment: `remote.find…().then(exists, doesNotExist)`