# Intern Leadfoot run commands conditionally

Tags: selenium, intern

Using Selenium driver, IE remains logged in between sessions while FF and Chrome do not. I would like to execute a few additional commands in a test based on the existence of the "signed-in" element ID.

How can I execute code based on a condition in intern?

Pseudocode:

```
return command
.get(require.toUrl('http://example.com/'))
.findById('signed-in-user')
.then(function(){
    command
        .findById('sign-out')
        .click()
})
```

But how do I handle the situation where signed-in-user does not exist?

This is a duplicate of this question here: [How to do conditional browser interactions with intern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634215/how-to-do-conditional-browser-interactions-with-intern)  but is regarding Intern 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround but it is slightly hacky.
Using a `findAll` command you can test if any elements are found (element exists) and take action on it.

Example:

```
            // Log out if logged in
            .findAllByCssSelector('#signed-in-user')
                .then(function(elems) {
                    if(elems.length > 0) {
                        command
                        .findById('signed-in-user')
                            .click()
                            .end()
                        .findByLinkText('Sign out')
                            .click()
                            .end()
                    }
                    return true;
                })
                .end()
```