# Functional testing conditionals with Intern/Leadfoot

Tags: selenium, intern

I am wishing to conditionally execute some commands/assertions depending on whether previous assertions succeeded or not.

I can't seem to find a way to nest `then` calls or conditionally execute things using the chaining syntax of leadfoot.

Here is my test (the returns at the end of each function is due to this being compiled coffeescript):

```
tdd.test(tableUrl, function() {
    this.timeout = 60000;
    return this.remote.get(require.toUrl("tests/pages/" + tableUrl))
    .setPageLoadTimeout(60000)
    .setFindTimeout(20000)
    .findByCssSelector('.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable')
    .then(null, function(err) {
      return assert.fail('', '', 'Table should exist');
    }).then(pollUntil(function() {
      var table;
      table = document.querySelector('.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable');
      if (table.querySelectorAll('tbody td').length > 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }, null, 20000, 500)).then(function() {
      console.log('Assertion succeeded: Table should have data');
      return assert.ok(true, 'Table should have data');
    }, function(err) {
      return assert.fail('', '', 'Table should have data');
    });
  });
```

When a table does not exist, both 'Table should exist' and 'Table should have data' assertions should be reported as failing. However, only the last assertion is failing. When I comment out the 'Table should have data' error callback, the 'Table should exist' assertion is reported as failing correctly.

What I would like to do is

1. test if a `table` exists (via findByCssSelector).

   a) If it exists, report that it exists and test to see that it has more than one `td` element. This is currently done via `pollUntil` to ensure that the command is complete/promise is resolved as soon as more than one `td` is found instead of waiting for the whole implicit wait time.

   b) If it does not exist, report that it does not exist.

I can't seem to find a way of **not** executing the error callback of the second 'Table should have data' poll if the first `findByCssSelector` fails, due to lack of conditionals and only the last assertion failure being reported in a test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So conditional branching *can* happen with `then` calls, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17669302/893630) addresses how to do conditional branching with intern.

The problem I was having was the [pollUntil](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/pollUntil.html) function not behaving the same way as a normal [leadfoot Command](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html) method due to the [function returning a callback function that returns a promise rather than a promise directly](https://github.com/theintern/leadfoot/issues/15#issuecomment-54563091).

This can be circumvented by wrapping the `pollUntil` in an anonymous function, immediately calling the `pollUntil` function using the `call` method, passing in the current `this` value due to [then](https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#then) setting the context of the callback to the Command object, and then finally chaining another Command.

This is what the above code turned into using correct conditional branching with `pollUntil`.

```
tdd.test(tableUrl, function() {
  this.timeout = 60000;
  return this.remote.get(require.toUrl("tests/pages/" + tableUrl))
  .setPageLoadTimeout(60000)
  .setFindTimeout(5000)
  .findByCssSelector('.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable')
  .then((function() {
    return pollUntil(function() {
      var table;
      table = document.querySelector('.dataTables_wrapper table.dataTable');
      if (table.querySelectorAll('tbody td').length > 1) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }, null, 20000, 500).call(this).then(function() {
      console.log('Assertion succeeded: Table should have data');
      return assert.ok(true, 'Table should have data');
    }, function(err) {
      return assert.fail('', '', 'Table should have data');
    });
  }), function(err) {
    return assert.fail('', '', "Table should exist. Error: " + err.name);
  });
});
```

Comment: is it possible with registerSuite instead of tdd?